# How to copy files into /usr/local/? (permission denied)

Tags: permissions, clipboard

I'm still a little new to Ubuntu and was wondering how I can copy files, in this case Aptana Studio, to /usr/local/ without being denied.

Is there a way to do it in terminal? Or a way to allow myself permission?  I should add that I am using 10.10 Desktop edition, not server.

Comment: Why do you want that? You're most likely looking for `/opt` or you want to install it in your home directory. `/usr` is managed by `apt`, so what ever you copy in there can change without notification or break your system.

Comment: @Bobby the Aptana installation instructions for linux advise to install it in /usr/local http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Installing_Aptana_on_Linux but I do agree with you /opt is the more "sensible place" to put it which is why I have it there especially if they get a ppa at launchpad could cause problems down the road.

Comment: So, it is better to place it on /opt?

Comment: Yes opt is classed as the place to put non package programs as the opt directory is not touched by the system so no automatic upgrades or removals you have to everything manually. BTW if you use XAMPP which I do (to lazy to install a proper lampp stack) this is where you would put it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways

1. Open Nautilus with sudo by typing `sudo -H nautilus` in terminal then copy the files as you would normally. Warning: I would close nautilus straight after so you don't accidently use it for moving normal files.
2. Open terminal and type `sudo cp file1 /usr/local/` obviously replacing `file1` with `aptana`
3. Add open as admin option to nautilus and open the local folder by right clicking and selecting open as administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I think it is too. I just am having a tough time getting it installed.

Answer (score 10):

`/usr/local` is a directory belonging to the user `root`, so you need to use `sudo` to achieve your end:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mydir
sudo cp file.txt /usr/local/mydir
```

for example.

Comment: You can also type `sudo -s`, which makes every command thereafter "sudo" until you exit, either with `exit` or `CTRL-D`.

Comment: @Scaine: `sudo su` does the same(just FYI).

Comment: Not quite, John.  `sudo su` will give you a root shell as root.  `sudo -s` will give you a root shell as /you/.  Try both and do an `echo $HOME` to see the difference.  `sudo su` is the equivalent to `sudo -i`.