# Having issues moving folder into lib

Tags: permissions

I cannot for some reason move a plugin folder for my server into `/usr/lib/name`

I get an error saying permission denied... I need this plugin to fix my issues... Does anyone know how I can get permission to perform this task?

Comment: did you use `sudo`?

Comment: No I was drag and drop I use Ubuntu Desktop

Comment: /usr is owned by root. I don't know the exact terminal command. but you can try `sudo nautilus` to get the file manager with root permissions

Comment: @THelper -- he doesn't want to change permissions, he wants to write into a system folder

Comment: Write `sudo nautilus` in the terminal and the file explorer will open with root access. then use that to move the plugin.

Comment: ya I attempted change folder permissions didn't work lol Im attempting to add or write into a system folder and its not going so well ;[ for my silly media server

Comment: Thank you Russo that worked but version of my plugin is not for LINUX like it said it was lol but thanks for solving my issue now I KNOW HOW TO DO IT

Comment: @Russo please post that as an answer

Comment: Please don't use `sudo nautilus` Use the `-H` flag when running graphical applications with `sudo`, eg `sudo -H nautilus` And definitely don't randomly change file & directory permissions of system directories

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/lib/name`, [like other system folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24952/how-to-copy-files-into-usr-local-permission-denied),  belongs to root. If you need to copy files there, you may use `sudo` that allows you to perform some tasks as root.

In the terminal, you can execute `cp -r` to perform a recursive copy

```
sudo cp -r <file> /usr/lib/<name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `sudo -H nautilus` in the terminal and the file explorer will open with root access. This will allow you to move the plugin.

You should be careful when doing this, as you can break your system by accidentally deleting critical files etc. Only use it when you really need it.

Comment: @Zanna, I didn't edit my answer after you have corrected my answer. Please check the edit history. I have now rolledback to your edit again.

Comment: Oh so sorry for my mistake; I didn't pay attention to the fact that someone else had edited it. :(